# How to perform an upsert on a table with both a primary key and UNIQUE column

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert, auto-increment

New to SQLite and trying to understand the upsert functionality.

I have a table with the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    contact_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    phone TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Let's say I insert a record:

```
INSERT INTO contacts (contact_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Jones', 'jjones@gmail.com', '888-867-5309');
```

How can I do an upsert that takes into account both the UNIQUE constraint (`email`) and the PK constraint ( `contact_id`) so that it handles either case since I don't know which constraint will fail.

I tried doing this:

```
INSERT INTO contacts (contact_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Jones', 'john.jones@gmail.com', '888-867-5309')
ON CONFLICT (contact_id, email) DO UPDATE
SET first_name='John', last_name='Jones', email='john.jones@gmail.com', phone='888-867-5309'
WHERE contact_id=1;
```

But I get the error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint

Doing them individually works just fine.

```
INSERT INTO contacts (contact_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Jones', 'john.jones@gmail.com', '888-867-5309')
ON CONFLICT (contact_id) DO UPDATE
SET first_name='John', last_name='Jones', email='john.jones@gmail.com', phone='888-867-5309'
WHERE contact_id=1;
```

```
INSERT INTO contacts (contact_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Jones', 'john.jones@gmail.com', '888-867-5309')
ON CONFLICT (email) DO UPDATE
SET first_name='John', last_name='Jones', email='john.jones@gmail.com', phone='888-867-5309'
WHERE email='john.jones@gmail.com';
```

I understand I get the error because the combination of columns doesn't meet a single constraint, it encompasses two. But how would I take both into account?

Comment: Maybe `INSERT OR REPLACE` will do what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you defined:

```
contact_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

`contact_id` is [`AUTOINCREMENT`](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) and you must **not** set explicitly a value for this column when you insert a new row (although SQLite would not complain if you do if there is no conflict).
So all you need is:

```
INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, email, phone)
VALUES ('John', 'Jones', 'john.jones@gmail.com', '888-867-5309')
ON CONFLICT (email) DO UPDATE
SET first_name='John', last_name='Jones', email='john.jones@gmail.com', phone='888-867-5309';
```

But, you defined also:

```
phone TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

so there are 2 `UNIQUE` constraints in your table.
For this case if you want SQLite to deal with conflicts from both columns you can use [`(INSERT OR) REPLACE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

```
REPLACE INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, email, phone)
VALUES('Johny', 'Jones', 'john.jones@gmail.com', '888-867-5309')
```

You must know that `REPLACE` inserts the new row if there is no conflict (for the columns `email` and `phone` in your case), but if there is a conflict then deletes the conflicting row or rows (because there would be 2 conflicting rows one for `email` and the other for `phone`) and inserts the new row.